# Как располагаются папки сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Не могу понять как правильно расположить папки для php кодов, картинок, страниц и т.д. по стандарту (если есть таковой=)) ну или по-нормальному по-человечески чтобы потом не было путаницы)

Comment: У Вас самописный движок ?

Comment: без движка)хочу с нуля сам..попробовать

Comment: ну да самописный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут всё просто - достаточно не кидать всё в одну кучу. Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно. Например, можно сделать так:

```
/www
    /img       -- изображения
    /js        -- скрипты
    /css       -- стили
    /pages     -- php-страницы
    index.php  -- заглавная страница
```

А вообще, делайте так, как вам будет удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

я бы на вашем месте взял любой популярный фреймворк и посмотрел как там организована структура.
велосипед это хорошо но хотелось бы видя чужой проект сразу понимать что где находится.

Comment: даже лучше наоборот. можно сделать велосипед, а потом посмотреть, как это делают правильные ребята

Answer (score 1):

```
app
    ...
system
    ...
www

     css
     js
     img 
     index.php
```

Comment: а другие странички?куда вставлять?

Comment: какие остальные?

Comment: @ukroficer, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: интересно, а что кидать в каталог system? ядро?

Comment: там ядро файлы каторые ты не будешь менять и проект в проекта классы БД и.т.д

Comment: @ukroficer почему бы их в app не закинуть? зачем такой разброс?

Comment: >> почему бы их в app не закинуть? зачем такой разброс?
так удобнее. файлы ядра ты просто не будешь использовать -- лежат они и лежат. а вот в папке app постоянно будешь копаться